# Nothing renders on Django Template

Tags: python, django

building a news aggregator. I am collecting reddit and twitter posts using their APIs, and then I create a model object for each post, which is stored in my database. I'm then passing in these post objects as context into my template, looping through the context in the template with the hope to display the posts 'html' attribute (A model field I created) onto the page, which in turn embeds the post onto the screen.

However,  I can't figure out why my template page is still blank. No errors are thrown, and the model objects are being created because I can see them in the admin panel. I'll provide my models.py, views.py, and template to be taken a glance at. I appreciate and am grateful for any help/advice.

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    root_url = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    html = models.TextField(default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

---

**views.py**

```
def main(request):
    all_posts = Post.objects.all
    context = {'posts': all_posts}
    return render(request, "test.html", context)
```

**template**

```
{% block content %} {% autoescape off %} 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <h3 class='text-center'>Twitter News</h3>
          {% for post in posts %}
            {% if post.post_type == 'twitter' %}
              <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
          {{ post.html }}
            {% endif %}
          <br>
          {% endfor %}
          <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <h3 class='text-center'>Reddit News</h3>
          {% for post in posts %}
            {% if post.post_type == 'reddit' %}
              <div class="mdl-card__media" id="timeline"></div>
                {{ post.html }}
            {% endif %}
          <br>
          {% endfor %}
          <script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endautoescape %}{% endblock %}
    
    
    <script async src="//embed.redditmedia.com/widgets/platform.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If that is the entire template I dont see `{% extends from base.html %}` or whatever parent template is your main one. So then `{% block content %}` wont work.

Comment: It's there, I just didn't post it in this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views.py, your attempt to create a queryset is missing the parenthesis on the `all` method:

```
all_posts = Post.objects.all()
```

You have mentioned in the comments that the `<br>` tags within the `{% for %}` loops are being rendered. This would indicate that when you check for `{% if post.post_type == 'twitter' %}` (and the equivalent for reddit), there are no matches.

Check your `Post` model in Django admin to ensure you have records with `post_type` values that equal 'twitter' and 'reddit'.

Comment: You're right, thanks for noticing. I did fix it but the problem still persists

Comment: @nick_rinaldi You mention in your question that the template is 'blank'. When you check the HTML source in your browser, are the `<br>` tags within your `{% for %}` loops still being generated?

Comment: Yes the <br> tags are beng generated

Comment: That solved it! I had to capitalize my "Twitter" and "Reddit" post types. Man, I should've noticed that. Thanks for the help